# How to check String is Palindrome or not Using WebMethods

Tags: webmethods

I want to check given string palindrome or not and I want to write the logic in WebMethods,
Is anyone help me on this, because I am new in the WebMethods..

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and you set up so we can better help you with you questions?

Comment: Hi @AvivLo this is the only task i have now, i need to create webmethods Flow which is checking the string, whether it is palindrome or not

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to write a Java service, with a Webmethods Flow this will be rather painful and not good for performance. In a Webmethods Java service you can use the same libraries as in a normal Java application

First Step, Create a Java service
[image: First Step, Create a Java service]

Define in- and output
[image: Define in- and output]

Than you get the input in java

```java
IDataMap map = new IDataMap(pipeline);
String stringToCheck = map.getAsString("stringToCheck");
```

Now its your turn to implement the logic to check for palindrome, you can simply use the put Method from the IDataMap Class to define the service output

```java
map.put("isPalindrome", palindromeCheckResult);
```

Comment: Can you explain  me with example ?

Comment: i enhance my answer with an example